# Singularity and plurality confusion

Tags: grammar

## We should not be confused with any other kind of issue.

## We should not be confused with any other kind of issues.

which one is grammatically right?

Comment: Related: See [Types of things vs. types of thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5539/2303) on our sister site, English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is acceptable. Which you actually use depends on the context of the sentence. How many other issues have you already spoken about? If just one, keep it singular; if many, then use the plural.

This mirrors the following, where both are grammatical:

> any other issue
>   any other issues

The addition of *kind of* doesn't really make a difference here—although different people may find that one version sounds better than another.

*Kind of issue* will sound natural to almost everybody—if a single issue is being discussed.

Deciding between *kind of issues*, *kinds of issue*, and *kinds of issues* (where there is a plural number of issues) is more subjective. Unless there is a specific reason to mention *kind*, if you think it causes confusion, I would just drop it in the plural case.

---

Note that in this particular sentence, it should almost certainly be *we should not be confused* ***by*** rather than *we should not be confused* ***with***.